# If $m$ unit vectors in $n$ dimensions have the same dot product, $u\cdot v=\lambda$ for all $u\neq v$, what values of $\lambda$ are possible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ be a positive integer with $n\geq 3$. For each positive integer $m$ with $m \geq 2$, find all real values $\lambda_m$ such that there are $m$ distinct unit vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $v_i · v_j = \lambda_m$ for all $i, j$ with $1\leq i<j \leq m$.

I have considered some examples but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: Hint: For unit vectors, the dot product is the cosine of the angle between them. So if you find the range for the pairwise common angles, you get the range for the lambdas.

Comment: can you give some more details.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $m\ge2$. The required vectors exist if and only if

1. $m\le n$ and $-\frac{1}{m-1}<\lambda<1$, or
2. $m\le n+1$ and $\lambda=-\frac{1}{m-1}$.

Assume that the vectors exist. Let them be the columns of a real $n\times m$ matrix $V$. Then
$$
V^TV=\pmatrix{1&\lambda&\cdots&\lambda\\ \lambda&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\ \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\lambda\\ \lambda&\cdots&\lambda&1}
=(1-\lambda)I_m+\lambda ee^T
$$
where $e\in\mathbb R^m$ denotes the vector of ones. Since $V^TV$ is positive semidefinite, the eigenvalues of $(1-\lambda)I_m+\lambda ee^T$, namely,
$$
1+(m-1)\lambda,\,\underbrace{1-\lambda,\,1-\lambda,\,\ldots,\,1-\lambda}_{m-1\text{ copies}},
$$
must be nonnegative and hence $\frac{-1}{m-1}\le\lambda\le 1$. However, the case $\lambda=1$ is impossible, otherwise we would have $\|v_1\|=\|v_2\|=v_1\cdot v_2=1$ and in turn $v_1=v_2$, which is a violates our requirement that the $v_i$s are distinct. Therefore $\lambda$ must be smaller than $1$. It is also impossible that $m-n\ge2$, otherwise $V^TV$ will have at least two zero eigenvalues and hence $\lambda=1$.

So, if $V$ exists, we must have $\frac{-1}{m-1}\le\lambda<1$ and $m-n\le1$. Yet, when $m-n=1$, $V^TV$ must be singular. As we have discussed previously, $V^TV$ cannot possess two or more zero eigenvalues and $\lambda$ cannot be equal to $1$. Therefore, when $m-n=1$, $V^TV$ has exactly one zero eigenvalue and that zero eigenvalue must be $1+(m-1)\lambda$ rather than $1-\lambda$. Hence $\lambda=-\frac{1}{m-1}$ in this case. This shows that the two conditions we mentioned at the beginning are indeed necessary.

Conversely, suppose either of the two conditions is satisfied. Then $A=(1-\lambda)I_m+\lambda ee^T$ is positive semidefinite. Let $r$ be the rank of $A$. Hence it can be written as $X^TX$ for some $r\times m$ matrix $X$ of full row rank (numerically one may use Cholesky decomposition or orthogonal diagonalisation to obtain $X$). If $X$ has any repeated columns, $X^TX$ will possess a principal $2\times2$ matrix with four identical elements, but this is impossible because all principal $2\times2$ matrices of $X^TX=A$ are in the form of $\pmatrix{1&\lambda\\ \lambda&1}$ and $\lambda<1$. Therefore $X$ has distinct columns. Now,

- if $m\le n$ and $-\frac{1}{m-1}<\lambda<1$, $A$ is positive definite, $r=m\le n$ and we may take $V=\pmatrix{X\\ 0_{(n-m)\times m}}$;
- if $m\le n+1$ and $\lambda=-\frac{1}{m-1}$, the nullity of $A$ is one, $r=m-1\le n$ and we may take $V=\pmatrix{X\\ 0_{(n+1-m)\times m}}$.

Comment: Yes, and I think it's nice to visualize some solutions to the $n=3$ case: For $m=3$, an equilateral triangle with fixed center grows down around the sphere, until it is coplanar with the center and the inner products are all $-1/2$. For $m=4$, we can only have a single size of regular tetrahedron inscribed in the sphere.